# tqdm and print / logging doesn't work properly (no linebreak for first logging / print statement)

Tags: python, logging, printing, tqdm

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import logging
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
    for _ in range(2000):
        a = i+8
    if i % 100 == 0:
        logging.warning("test")
```

This outputs this:

```
  0%|          | 0/1000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
100%|██████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 996982.17it/s]
```

I'm fine with the bar refreshing and printing again (without the argument `leave=True` basically) but there is no linebreak for the first warning. It doesn't work very well either with a `print("test")`:

```
  0%|          | 0/1000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
100%|██████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 20526.40it/s]
```

Any idea how to have a proper linebreak for the first print / logging? I can't add "\n" because otherwise i'm gonna have way too many linebreaks for the following print messages. And adding a "if this is the first message then add "\n" otherwise don't" sounds like a dirty way of bypassing the problem.

I've seen this post ([tqdm with logger on separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71520288/tqdm-with-logger-on-separate-lines)) but this was no answers apart from "do your own tqdm" which i don't really like because i like just having to do `tqdm(my_iterable)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the status bar by calling the `clear` method of the `tqdm` object before writing output to stdout or stderr.

To make the call to the `clear` method happen automatically for each output, you can create a context manager that patches both `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with a wrapper function that calls the `clear` method of a given `tqdm` object before writing a message to the original `sys.stderr`:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tqdm_output(tqdm, write=sys.stderr.write):
    def wrapper(message):
        if message != '\n':
            tqdm.clear()
        write(message)
        if '\n' in message:
            tqdm.display()

    with patch('sys.stdout', sys.stderr), patch('sys.stderr.write', wrapper):
        yield tqdm
```

So that you can put the iteration within the context manager and use the logger normally:

```
with tqdm_output(tqdm(range(1000))) as trange:
    for i in trange:
        if i % 100 == 0:
            logging.warning("test")
```

And it would output:

```
WARNING:root:test                                                        
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test                                                        
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test                                                        
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test                                                        
WARNING:root:test
WARNING:root:test                                                        
100%|██████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 1797.66it/s]
```

Same with using `print`:

```
with tqdm_output(tqdm(range(1000))) as trange:
    for i in trange:
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('test')
```

which outputs:

```
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
test                                                                     
100%|███████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:05<00:00, 181.55it/s]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/GentleShallowScan