# How can I record progress bar output from external process through the logging module

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, progress-bar, stdout

I am writing a python script to:

- excute an application (mcu_flash.exe)
- use logging module to record the output info of this application to file and stdout.

I've basically completed the script, but unfortunately, the application (mcu_flash.exe) contains a progress bar output, which results in **many rows of unused progress bar logs** in **log file** generated by logging modules:

```
......
[2023-01-19 17:51:11,235] - [INFO] : Start flash code:  
[2023-01-19 17:52:54,818] - [INFO] : [                                                  ][0%]
[                                                  ][0%]
[                                                  ][1%]
[                                                  ][1%]
......
```

The output in terminal seems much more normal:

```
......
[2023-01-19 18:59:18,957] - [INFO] : Start flash code:
[==================================================][100%]                              ][0%]
......
```

How can I record the final result of application's progress bar output in one line, with logging module?

Here is my specific code:

```
def ToDoBat(dir, command):
    os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, cwd=dir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    curline = p.stdout.readline()
    while (curline != b''):
        try:
            curline = curline.decode(encoding='utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            try:
                curline = curline.decode(encoding='gbk')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                curline = "[Error] can't decode the command line"
        logging.info(curline.strip("\r\n"))
        curline = p.stdout.readline()
    p.wait()
    return p.returncode

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format="[%(asctime)s] - [%(levelname)s] : %(message)s",
                        encoding='uft-8',
                        handlers=[
                            logging.FileHandler(
                                filename=os.path.join(os.sep, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "log.log"),
                                mode='a',
                                encoding='utf-8'),
                            logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
                        ])
    ToDoBat(os.path.join(os.sep, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "mcu_flash.exe")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't answer my question. In [Python Progress Bar THROUGH Logging Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897756/python-progress-bar-through-logging-module), the function in python controls the progress bar output, but here I just execute the mcu_flash.exe with popen which controls the the progress bar output. Thank you for this.

Comment: Now I'm  taking temporary measures:  using the filter class of logging module to mask this progress bar ouput from mcu_flash.exe. Look forward to more ideas :)